# How do I check if users input is equal to a certain value in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, visual-studio-code, chatbot

Hi I'm currently making a simple version of a chatbot, but I have some issues with my code. I want to check if the user input is equal to a value in my array. What I currently have looks like this:

```
var digibord = [
    {
        name: ["digibord","smartboard","schoolbord"]
    }
]

function handleMessage(message) {
    if (message.includes(digibord)) {
        Digibord();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have little experience with javascript so I could use some help...

Comment: Try this `digibord[0].name.includes(message)`. That is because you need to check whether `digibord[0].name` array includes value which is provided by the `message` variable, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var digibord = [
    {
        name: ["digibord","smartboard","schoolbord"]
    }
];

function handleMessage(message) {
    digibord.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (value.name.includes(message)) {
            //Digibord();
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}

handleMessage("digibord");
```

Comment: THANK YOUUUU <3, it took me way too long LOL

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check if message exist in your predefined array. `indexOf` returns -1 if it's not found.

```
if (digibord.indexOf(message) > -1) {
    //In the array!
} else {
    //Not in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the case of a chatbot you may want to use regular expressions instead

```
var digibord = [{
    name: ["digibord","smartboard","schoolbord"]
}];


function handleMessage(message) {
    for (item in digibord[0].name) {
        var re = new RegExp( item, "g" );
        if (re.test(item)) {
           // Do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you a bit:
your digibord is an Array of objects - in your case with only one object.
The object member 'name' is an Array of the names. 
To address this Array of names you need: digibord[0].name as shown in the example of teeyo. "includes" is a method of the Array. Therefore your code could look like:

```
 var digibord = [
    {
        name: ["digibord","smartboard","schoolbord"]
    }
];

function handleMessage(message) {
if (digibord[0].name.includes(message)) {
    Digibord();
  }
}
```